# PHP replace first letter with new string - wordpress title

Tags: php, string, str-replace

What am I doing wrong?

```
$title = get_the_title();
$firstLetter = $title[0];
$title[0] = '<span class = "wrapBlue">' . $firstLetter . '</span>';     

echo $title; // comes out with weird switched around string?
```

`get_the_title()` is a wordpress function.

`var_dump on $title` gives a string of length 21.

`var_dump on $firstLetter` gives a string containing the correct character of length 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know `$title[0]` refers to the first letter - but what you're trying to assign isn't a letter. Try something like this:

```
$title = '<span class = "wrapBlue">' . $firstLetter . '</span>' . substr($title, 1);
```

Comment: Is it because the variable $firstLetter is now a pointer to the first char memory?

Comment: And thanks, that's working great. Ill mark as answer when I can.

Comment: ahh I understand.. I'm replacing a char with a new amount of memory... So the one char of 4 bytes is overloaded with however many bytes my new line is... If I add more to the prefix of the array, that may do the job.. but your tech works great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$title = get_the_title();
$firstLetter = substr($title, 0, 1);
$title .= '<span class = "wrapBlue">' . $firstLetter . '</span>' . substr($title, 1, strlen($title);
echo $title;
```

Oneliner:

```
echo '<span class = "wrapBlue">' . substr(get_the_title(), 0, 1) . '</span>' . substr(get_the_title(), 1, strlen(get_the_title());
```

Comment: I did this before but thought it silly if you could indeed do this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Comment: it does... strings are arrays of characters. and it does echo the correct character. You example will definitely echo "l"

Comment: "this does NOT print the first letter." - wrong. it does print the first letter.

Comment: `$title .= '<span class = "wrapBlue">' . $firstLetter . '</span>' . substr($title, 1, strlen($title);`: perhaps not `.=`? And the substr needs another closing bracket.